# Include an Ecmascript 6 class using Google Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-closure-compiler

How do I include an Ecmascript 6 class when using Google Closure Compiler?

E.g., I have a class in 'stuff/dog.js':

```
class dog {
    constructor() {
        …
    }
    addLeg() {
        this.legs++;
    }
}
```

And I want to include it in 'stuff/pound.js' so I can write:

```
let rex = new Dog();
```

How should this be handled?  I can't use stuff.dog as a class name so passing the calls to goog.provide() doesn't seem to be an option.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit: Using the latest (20160517 1.0)** version of Closure Compiler, this can be handled with plain Ecmascript 6:

Animal.js:

```
export default class{
    constructor(){
        this.legs = [];
    }
    addLeg(legId){
        this.legs.push( legId );
    }
}
```

Dog.js:

```
import Animal from './Animal';

export default class extends Animal {
    constructor(){
        super();
        [1,2,3,4].forEach(leg=>this.addLeg(leg));
        console.log( 'Legs: ' + this.legs.toString() );
    }
}
```

Though it does give me a warning for some reason: [Closure Compiler warns "Bad type annotation. Unknown type …" when Ecmascript 6 class is extended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577183/closure-compiler-warns-bad-type-annotation-unknown-type-when-ecmascript-6-c)

Comment: Are you already using Closure Compiler? If you're running it in `ECMASCRIPT_6` mode, ES6 class definitions should be recognized in the same way as legacy prototype "class" definitions; they aren't really a special case. If you aren't, you'll need to add something like `goog.provide('dog')` and `goog.require('dog')` to your separate files.

Comment: I'm using it, but I'm new to it.  When you say 'running it in ECMASCRIPT_6 mode' do you mean setting language_in to 'ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT'?  
I have that set, and I've tried export and import, goog.provide() and goog.require(), some other random key combinations, and nothing seems to work...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. There's not really enough information in this question to answer properly (Closure has a lot of options/flags so it would be good to have a full example of what you've tried), but: You may want to consider using `goog.module`, the newer system which behaves more like other node.js modules systems, though it's still path-independent (you can goog.provide() names from anywhere). [Here's a random example](https://github.com/vxq/js/blob/f1f0d354d77a39ebf403031fc719aeb150b7f952/vxq/worlds/turtles.js) using ES6 classes with `goog.module()`, `goog.require()` and `exports`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 classes can be assigned to namespaces:

```
stuff.dog = class { } 
new stuff.dog();
```

Comment: Thanks! I have it working using your answer and the advice of Jeremy about goog.module().  I'll add another answer so I can add formatting …

Answer (score 1):

Using the answers from Jeremy and Chad (thanks, guys!) I managed to get my class imported using something similar to this:

'stuff/dog.js':

```
goog.module('canine');
canine.dog = class {
    constructor() {
        …
    }
    addLeg() {
        this.legs++;
    }
}
```

'stuff/pound.js':

```
goog.require('canine');
let rex = new canine.Dog();
```

One thing that wasn't obvious to me is that the namespace ('canine') doesn't need to have anything to do with the class name or filename/path.

Comment: Do you mean `goog.require('canine');` in that second code snippet? And yeah, namespaces are arbitrary! But if you want, you can choose to export the class name directly (by doing `goog.module('Dog')` then `Dog = class {` or `exports = class {` or something depending on your setup).

Comment: Whoops, yeah.  Thanks again!