# Closure Compiler warns "Bad type annotation. Unknown type …" when Ecmascript 6 class is extended

Tags: class, ecmascript-6, google-closure-compiler

I'm getting a warning for every Ecmascript 6 class that inherits from another class when compiling with Closure Compiler:

I've dumbed things down as much as possible and still get the warning:

```
/src/main/js/com/tm/dev/Dog.js: WARNING - Bad type annotation. Unknown type module$$src$main$js$com$tm$dev$Animal.default
```

The compiled code does run correctly.  (I've tried a number of annotations which only made things worse.)  Anyone know what's expected here?

Animal.js:

```
export default class{
    constructor(){
        this.legs = [];
    }
    addLeg(legId){
        this.legs.push( legId );
    }
}
```

Dog.js:

```
import Animal from './Animal';

export default class extends Animal {
    constructor(){
        super();
        [1,2,3,4].forEach(leg=>this.addLeg(leg));
        console.log( 'Legs: ' + this.legs.toString() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A hint is in the warning message, though it would obviously be confusing if you're not familiar with [Closure Compiler's annotation inspection](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#overview).

> The Closure Compiler can use data type information about JavaScript variables to provide enhanced optimization and warnings. JavaScript, however, has no way to declare types.
>
> Because JavaScript has no syntax for declaring the type of a variable, you must use comments in the code to specify the data type.

*(The following is untested.)*

Closure Compiler is reporting that in `Dog.js` it does not recognise the "type" `Animal`. This is because you are exporting an unnamed class expression: `export default class`.

So you could give your class a name (`export default class Animal`) and Closure Compiler may recognise the token `Animal` when it is consumed in `Dog.js`.

And you can also give your class a JSDoc that marks it as a `@constructor`:

```
/**
 * Animal.
 * @constructor
 */
export default class Animal {}
```

Comment: Thanks for tracking that down. This is a bug. Can you file an issue for this? https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth Sure :-) The bug being that it doesn't recognise the import name of the unnamed class as a type?

Comment: ([here's the submitted issue](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/1825))

Comment: Thanks! So I should mark the class as a constructor, not the 'constructor' method within the class?

Comment: I added the class name as above (export default class Animal) and still received the warning.  Adding the annotation above the class gives an addition warning: " WARNING - Misplaced function annotation. This JSDoc is not attached to a function node. Are you missing parentheses?"

Comment: My apologies. I didn't state in my answer that I had not tested the suggestions. (As classes de-sugar to functions I expected that the annotation would work.) Alas, it looks like my assumptions were incorrect... Hopefully the issue on GitHub will be picked up and this will be resolved soon.